# With container set maximum size, image still exceed container

Tags: html, css

I have div1, div2 and an image with the following structure:

```html
<div1>
  <div2>
    <img>
  </div2>
</div1>
```

**div1:**

```css
position: absolute;
top, width, height: somevalue;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
```

**div2:**

```css
position: relative
max-width: 100%;
max-height: 100%;
object-fit: contain;
border: 3px red solid;
& img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%; 
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin: auto;
}
```

However the large image still exceeds `div1`. I have tried putting `display:contents` in div2 which works fine, but I need extra image siblings position absolute to the first image, which doesn't work with `display:content`(sort of mistakenly positioning absolute to div1).

If I put `display:absolute` inside `img` then I can't see the image, there is only a red dot(come from div2 border) in the center.

Let's forget about the image siblings, why the main displaying image still exceed div2's maximum size?

Answer (score 0):

I just copied your code and placed it into a snippet and it seems to be working correctly?

If I was you I would ensure that no other styles are overwriting what you have shared in your question.

```css
.div1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.div2 {
  position: relative
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  border: 3px red solid;
}

.div2 img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%; 
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
  </div>
</div>
```